# Installing "joomla" problem, how to turn off "output buffering" on PHP?

Tags: joomla

I installed lampp, and then i downloaded newest version of "joomla" and i unpacked it to

> /var/www/joomla/

then i went to my browser and i opened this link :
localhost/joomla
so it opened the installation of joomla, then i chose language and went to the next page, in that page it showed me that the "output buffering is on and it should be off so i run this command on the terminal:

> sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

i opened php.ini and then i found this :

> output buffering: 4096

i changed it to :

> output buffering: off

then i saved php.ini and i refreshed the installation of joomla but output buffering was still on.
how can i turn this off?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/78281/12864)? It answers your issue here and in the [other question](http://askubuntu.com/q/230906/12864) you posted. I've also asked a related question [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/205441/12864), with a great answer from @Sergey that might help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fixed it by restarting apache2, i simply ran this command:

> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

Take care when using a graphic interface application, you must use `gksudo` instead of `sudo`. So replace your command by:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Comment: That's not true. `sudo` works totally fine, the only difference is, it asks for a password in the terminal.